# Retrieve subscriber status changes via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

I need to get the information about subscriber status change using SFMC API.
Is there an API call that can get current status of subscriber along with the date on which the status was last modified?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please be sure to include more information inside your future questions. You need to include an indepth use case, existing code/attempts you have made to solve the issue and any problems/errors you are getting with it.  Please see here for helpful advice on how to ask a question (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

@Milio try like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis- 
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" 
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity- 
 utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>******</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- 
  username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>                    
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>           
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" 
     xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <Property>ListID</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>4454</Value>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
   </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This will return a rowset of all subscribers on a list, not a specific subscriber and you did not request the subscriberkey, meaning that there will be no way to link the returned results to the specific subscriber. There also is no context on WHY or HOW this solves his issue. Please update your answer to include more details and provide a solution that is more relevant to the question. You are almost there and deserve the recognition for the solution, but without the above context, it is not viable.

Comment: The purpose of my request is to provide an external system with an api call that can be used to retrieve subscriber status updates (mainly these three information: subsckriberKey, status, ModifiedDate) from AllSubscribers.

Comment: @pkharries I'm testing your solution and work fine (great) though I can't retrieve the email address in result.Furthermore I am finding however that using a ComplexFilterPart the api call does not return a list. Why?